# ADD TO CART & CHECKOUT in html

Tags: javascript, html-table

Can I add an "Add to Cart" and "Checkout" buttons here?

I think I need to re-write all of this in order for me to create this buttons because I think it will require more PHP contents. Any tips or answers?

```js
 var Cost;

 function tally() {
     Cost = 0;
     if (document.orderform.item1.checked) {
       val = document.getElementById("Item1").value;
       Cost = Cost + (val * 1765.00);
     }
     if (document.orderform.item2.checked) {
       val = document.getElementById("Item2").value;
       Cost = Cost + (val * 1765.00);
     }
     if (document.orderform.item3.checked) {
       val = document.getElementById("Item3").value;
       Cost = Cost + (val * 9900.00);
     }
     if (document.orderform.item4.checked) {
       val = document.getElementById("Item4").value;
       Cost = Cost + (val * 5060.00);
     }
     if (document.orderform.item5.checked) {
       val = document.getElementById("Item5").value;
       Cost = Cost + (val * 6600.00);

       Cost = peso(Cost);

       document.orderform.Total.value = "P" + Cost;
     }

     function peso(amount) {
       amount = parseInt(amount * 100);
       amount = parseFloat(amount / 100);
       var x = Math.floor(amount);

       if (amount == x && (amount - x) == 0) {
         amount = amount + ".00";
         return amount;
       }

       if ((amount * 10) - (x * 10) == 0) {
         amount = amount + "0";
         return amount;
       }

       if ((amount * 100) - (x * 100) == 0) {
         amount = amount;
         return amount;
       }
       return amount;
     }

     function CalculateTotal(orderform) {
       Cost = 0;

       if (document.orderform.item1.checked) {
         val = document.getElementById("Item1").value;
         Cost = Cost + (val * 1765.00);
       }
       if (document.orderform.item2.checked) {
         val = document.getElementById("Item2").value;
         Cost = Cost + (val * 1765.00);
       }
       if (document.orderform.item3.checked) {
         val = document.getElementById("Item3").value;
         Cost = Cost + (val * 9900.00);
       }
       if (document.orderform.item4.checked) {
         val = document.getElementById("Item4").value;
         Cost = Cost + (val * 5060.00);
       }
       if (document.orderform.item5.checked) {
         val = document.getElementById("Item5").value;
         Cost = Cost + (val * 6600.00);
       }
       Cost = peso(Cost);

       document.orderform.Total.value = "P" + Cost;
     }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Nike</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table align=center width=1100 cellspacing=20>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <center>

          <body text="white">
            <img src="banner2.jpg">
        </center>
        <center>
          <div id="wrap">
            <ul class="navbar">
              <li> <a href="Main.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li> <a href="Products.html">Products</a>
                <ul>
                  <li> <a href="adidas.html">Adidas</a>
                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="Nike.html">Nike</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="login.php">Log-in</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
                  </li>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <center>
            <frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
              <form method="post" name="orderform">
                <table border="1" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><font color="white"><center>Name</font>
                    </td>
                    <td width=70><font color="white"><center>Price</font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25%"><font color="white"><center>Picture</font>
                    </td>
                    <td><font color="white"><center>Description</font>
                    </td>
                    <td><font color="white"><center>Stocks</font>
                    </td>
                    <td><font color="white"><center>Quantity</font>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            </frameset>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="item1_chosen" onclick="tally()">
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>Kobe BHM<br>Men's T-shirt</font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>P1,765.00</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="nike\1.jpg" width=257 height=200>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white">
 <ul>
  <li>Ribbed crew neck with interior taping</li>
  <li>Fabric: 100% cotton</li>
  <li>Machine Wash</li>
 </ul></font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>5</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <select name="Item1" onChange="CalculateTotal(orderform)" id="Item1">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="item2_chosen" onclick="tally()">
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>KD BHM<br>Men's T-shirt</font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>P1,765.00</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="nike\2.jpg" width=257 height=200>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white">
 <ul>
  <li>Ribbed crew neck with interior taping</li>
  <li>Fabric: 100% cotton</li>
  <li>Machine Wash</li>
 </ul></font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>5</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <select name="Item2" onChange="CalculateTotal(orderform)" id="Item2">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="item3_chosen" onclick="tally()">
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>Flyknit Air Max</font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>P9,900.00</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="nike\3.jpg" width=257 height=230>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white">
 <ul>
  <li>Full-length Max Air for maximum, flexible cushioning</li>
  <li>Ultralight Flyknit upper</li>
  <li>Flywire tech integrates with the laces for a dynamic, supportive fit</li>
  <li>Sculpted Cushion for plush cushioning, springy resilience and impact protection</li>
  <li>Flex grooves align with the Max Air unit for more natural range of motion</li>
  <li>Reflective elements enhance visibility in low light</li>
  <li>Weight: 12.8 ounces (Men's size 10)</li>
 </ul></td></font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>5</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <select name="Item3" onChange="CalculateTotal(orderform)" id="Item3">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="item4" value="item4_chosen" onclick="tally()">
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>Nike Air Zoom Pegasus 31 Flash</font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>P5,060.00</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="nike\4.jpg" width=257 height=220>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white">
 <ul>
  <li>Nike Zoom Air unit under the heel delivers low-profile, highly responsive cushioning</li>
  <li>Ultralight three-layer mesh upper repels water to help keep feet dry while providing superior support and ventilation</li>
  <li>Allover reflectivity enhances visibility in low light</li>
  <li>Waffle outsole with environmentally preferred rubber for durability and exceptional multi-surface traction</li>
  <li>Weight: 11 ounces (Men's size 10)</li>
 </ul>
    </td></font>
                <td><font color="white"><center>5</font>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <select name="Item4" onChange="CalculateTotal(orderform)" id="Item4">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="item5" value="item5_chosen" onclick="tally()">
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>KD7</font>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white"><center>P6,600.00</font>
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src='nike\5.jpg' width=257 height=200>
              </td>
              <td><font color="white">
 <ul>
  <li>Flywire design and midfoot strap provide lightweight lockdown</li>
  <li>Hybrid design blends flexibility and support to give you speed and strength on every step</li>
  <li>Visible Nike Zoon Unit delivers ultra-responsive cushioning</li>
  <li>Hyperposite construction helps support the rear foot</li>
  <li>Rubber outsole for durability and traction</li>
 </ul>
    </td></font>
                <td><font color="white"><center>5</font>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <select name="Item5" onChange="CalculateTotal(orderform)" id="Item5">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <font size=5 font color="white">Total <input type="text" name="Total" value="P0" size="7"></font>

            </form>

</html>
```

Comment: Need some context dude?

Comment: What exactly is a context lol

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't explain your problem well, so all I can do is answer the question you asked.

> Can I add an "Add to Cart" and "Checkout" buttons here?

Yes, you can easily add html buttons to the form for either checkout or add to cart. Looking at your page, I can't tell exactly what the page is supposed to be, but just from guessing, it is a general list, and you can select the amount on the right and use the checkboxes on the left to determine which ones to take action on -- either adding to the cart or checking out right now with the selected items.

Just add html for the buttons wherever you would like them, and then add in some ajax jquery calls to handle the calls on the server (php).

As for tips/advice:
If your products are completely static, you don't really need to rewrite what you have. However, when calculating the price, actually compute it on the server rather than trusting the data sent from the client. If your products are bound to change, you should really read the data from the database and populate your page based on that...